# Returning dynamic object structure

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm having some issues with returning a dynamic object. I'm using a [react-native chart library](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts), which requires me to return the data like so:

```
return [{
      'Manually Sold': { value: manuallySoldValue },
      'Trailing Stop Loss': { value: trailingStopLossValue },
      'Manual Short': { value: manualShortValue },
      'Profit': { value: profitValue },
      'Manual Buy': { value: manualBuy },
      'Strategy': { value: strategy },
      'Manual Close Short': { value: manualCloseShort },
      'available': { value: available },
      'in open positions': { value: inOpenPositions },
      'reserved': { value: reserved },
    }];
```

Which works fine, if the keys won't change.

**`StackedBarChart` rendering:**

```
stackedBarChart(counts, triggers) {
    return (
      <View>
        <StackedBarChart
          style={{ height: 10 }}
          colors={this.triggerColors()}
          contentInset={{ top: 30, bottom: 30 }}
          data={this.triggerValues(counts)}
          horizontal={true}
          keys={this.triggerKeys(counts)}
          valueAccessor={({ item, key }) => item[key].value}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

**this.triggerColors**

```
triggerColors() {
  return ['#00c8c6', '#44baf1', '#c7e486', '#efdc6c'];
}
```

**this.triggerKeys**

```
triggerKeys(data) {
  return Object.keys(data);
}
```

**Current implementation to build the required structure:**

```
triggerValues(data) {
    // The trigger values can be a lot more, so this needs to be dynamic
    const keys = this.triggerKeys(data);
    let manuallySoldValue = '';
    let trailingStopLossValue = '';
    let manualShortValue = '';
    let profitValue = '';
    let manualBuy = '';
    let strategy = '';
    let manualCloseShort = '';
    let available = '';
    let inOpenPositions = '';
    let reserved = '';

    keys.map((key) => {
      switch (key) {
        case 'Manually Sold':
          manuallySoldValue = data[key];
          break;
        case 'Trailing Stop Loss':
          trailingStopLossValue = data[key];
          break;
        case 'Manual Short':
          manualShortValue = data[key];
          break;
        case 'Profit':
          profitValue = data[key];
          break;
        case 'Manual Buy':
          manualBuy = data[key];
          break;
        case 'Strategy':
          strategy = data[key];
          break;
        case 'Manual Close Short':
          manualCloseShort = data[key];
          break;
        case 'available':
          available = data[key];
          break;
        case 'in open positions':
          inOpenPositions = data[key];
          break;
        case 'reserved':
          reserved = data[key];
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });

    return [{
      'Manually Sold': { value: manuallySoldValue },
      'Trailing Stop Loss': { value: trailingStopLossValue },
      'Manual Short': { value: manualShortValue },
      'Profit': { value: profitValue },
      'Manual Buy': { value: manualBuy },
      'Strategy': { value: strategy },
      'Manual Close Short': { value: manualCloseShort },
      'available': { value: available },
      'in open positions': { value: inOpenPositions },
      'reserved': { value: reserved },
    }];
  }
```

That would work if only the keys were set in stone. So I would like to build that part where the amount and keys won't matter. I've tried to build it with iteration over the data object (example objects below), but I can't seem to get the correct structure as mentioned below.

**Example of data objects:**

```
{available: "46.09", in open positions: "53.91", reserved: "0.00"}
```

-

```
{Manual Buy: 11, Manual Close Short: 7, Strategy: 42}
```

-

```
{Trailing Stop Loss: 3, Manual Short: 7, Profit: 46, Manually Sold: 5}
```

If you need any more information, please ask.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Object.keys` function to get the list of object keys and iterate them to create the structure you want. Please see the sample code below.

```js
const data = {
  "Trailing Stop Loss": 3,
  "Manual Short": 7,
  "Profit": 46,
  "Manually Sold": 5
};

const result = {};

Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
  result[key] = {
    value: data[key]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This will return `[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`, which is invalid to the lib. See my question for the required response.

Comment: @KevinEtore I have updated the code to follow the structure you want. My intent was to give you a direction on how to proceed.

Comment: This doesn't return the given output at all

Comment: @adiga The above code does not return anything since it is not written as a function. The code snippet just creates the required object structure in the ```result``` variable.

Comment: This gets you only the keys which are prsent in the `data`. Not all 10 keys mentioned in the output

Comment: @adiga From the question, I understand that the number of keys and the key names can be dynamic and not just the 10 keys shown in the question.

Comment: @Vivek OP hasn't provided a [mcve]. I just meant from their sample data objects, there were several missing keys. Waste of my time

Answer (score 1):

Update:

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the `data` and create another object with a nested structure:

```js
function triggerValues(data) {
  const output = Object.entries(data)
                       .reduce((r, [key, value]) => ({ ...r, [key]: { value } }), {});
    
  return [output]
}

console.log(triggerValues({available: "46.09", "in open positions": "53.91", reserved: "0.00"}))
console.log(triggerValues({"Manual Buy": 11, "Manual Close Short": 7, Strategy: 42}))
```

You can create an array of default keys and use simple [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops

```js
function triggerValues(data) {
  const defaultKeys = [
    "Manually Sold",
    "Trailing Stop Loss",
    "Manual Short",
    "Profit",
    "Manual Buy",
    "Strategy",
    "Manual Close Short",
    "available",
    "in open positions",
    "reserved"
  ];

  const output = {};

  for (const key of defaultKeys) {
    if (key in data)
      output[key] = { value: data[key] }
    else
      output[key] = { value: '' }
  }

  return [output]
}

console.log(triggerValues({available: "46.09", "in open positions": "53.91", reserved: "0.00"}))
console.log(triggerValues({"Manual Buy": 11, "Manual Close Short": 7, Strategy: 42}))
```

Comment: I like this implementation, but I kind of want an implementation without a default object. Because there are a lot of default keys, and I don't want to write them all out.

Comment: @KevinEtore you gotta define the keys somewhere. An array of keys would work too.

Comment: I was afraid of that.. At least the spread syntax makes it cleaner

Comment: @KevinEtore What exactly do mean by "*dynamically build object*"? How can you build an object without knowing what keys to add. You can either get it from a config or from database. You have to have it defined somewhere. I have added another approach with with an array of keys.

Comment: I guess I wasn't that clear in my explanation, sorry for that. All the `keys` are  available in my `data` object, So I can use `Object.keys` to fill up your `defaultKeys`.

Comment: @KevinEtore So, it's just a transformation from one structure to other? You have given 3 "*Example of data objects*" and they are all missing keys. Please create [mcve] from next time

Comment: @KevinEtore I have updated the code. A simple `reduce` should create the expected data

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't familiar with the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples. I'll try and create it in future posts.